# Fill DataSet with DataTable

Tags: c#, dataset

```
private static DataSet GetAuctionItemsDataSet()
{
    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapt = DataAdapter;
    DataSet filler = new DataSet();

    adapt.Fill(filler.Tables["AuctionItems"]);
    adapt.Fill(filler.Tables["Bids"]);

    return filler;
}
```

I want the the `SqlDataAdapter` to populate a new `DataSet` with records from the db. The `DataSet` should contain tables "AuctionItems" and "Bids" I think I am close but cannot seem to find the answer.

Comment: @JeremyChild why such a patronising reply? The idea of SO is people get to post code and people help. We have to assume people have googled..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To populate the `DataSet` try following syntax,

```
DataSet filler = new DataSet();
adapt.Fill(filler,"AuctionItems");
adapt.Fill(filler,"Bids");
```